# Downloading Wikipedia

Tags: internet, download, wikipedia

How can I download a specific set of the Wikipedia database? In particular, I'm interested in downloading all articles that fall under the mathematics portal and possibly the computer science portal. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a software called [Kiwix](http://www.kiwix.org/), which is really easy to use.

**EDIT**

Wikipedia provide a tool to extract a subset of its content. You can search for "Mathematics" [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export), and then export every article within this category. You'll get a .xml file which you can browse using one of the listed tools [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Dynamic_HTML_generation_from_a_local_XML_database_dump).

Comment: If you try to use `Special:Export` this way, it will only export the 7 articles that are directly under `Category:Mathematics`, not any of the other ten thousand math articles on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Media Wiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuick_start_guide).

Comment: It'd be great if you could expand your post a little, explaining how to achieve what the OP needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the `*-pages-articles.xml.bz2` from [Wikimedia backup dumps site](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html) and process them with [WikiTaxi](http://www.wikitaxi.org/delphi/doku.php/products/wikitaxi/index)(download in upper left corner). Wikitaxi Import tool will create a `.taxi`(around 15Gb for Wikipedia) file out of the `.bz2` file. That file will be used by WikiTaxi program to search through articles. The experience is very similar to the browser experience, **with all articles available to the time** of the dump, but without the images.

Or you can use [Kiwix](http://www.kiwix.org/index.php/Main_Page) faster to setup because has the database is already made (but quite old), but  WikiTaxi has the advantage that you can have the latest updated content.

Answer (score 1):

go to en.wikipedia.org
on the left sidebar, under "tools", click on "special pages".

in the new page, under "page tools" click on "export pages".

on the new page, type the name of each category you want. for example type mathematics (as shown in the picture below) and hit add.

[image]

then you should install Mediawiki and go to similar path and select "import pages".